# On abstain votes

Tags: governance

On ***open gov***, we have 3 options, Yay Nay and Abstain.

Do abstain votes count as a vote and if so does it affect the threshold curve.

I am wondering because if this is the case the word abstain may be misleading and should be renamed to neutral.

Thanks

edit: This is for open gov, not gov 1

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [moonbeam post about Open Gov](https://moonbeam.network/blog/opengov/) where the approval process for a proposal is better explained.

The key take away from this post is that in order for a proposal to pass it must meet a certain approval and support threshold. Where approval takes into account only ayes and nays, and Support also takes into account abstentions to calculate the curve.

Now the reason why the third option is "**abstain**" and not "**neutral**" is because both concepts imply very different things.

- Abstaining to vote means choosing not to cast a vote or deliberately refraining from voting on a particular issue or in an election. It can be due to various reasons such as a lack of interest, disagreement with all the available options, or a protest against the system or process.
- Being neutral in voting means casting a vote without taking a stance or expressing a preference for any particular option or candidate. It implies remaining impartial and not favoring any specific choice.

A neutral vote would imply an active participation and decision on the voting process from the users perspective on the voting process. Whereas abstaining implies that the user doesn't get directly involved in the proposal.